# Mapping a View using Entity Framework 6

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, view, entity-framework-6

I have a View in **SQL Server** and I junt want to retrieve data from this view using **EF6**.

I've added:

- Domain class `vw_foo`
- Context `DbSet<vw_foo>`
- Mapping `internal class vw_foo : EntityTypeConfiguration<vw_foo>`

  `{
      public vw_foo()
      {
          ToTable("vw_foo", "myDB");
      }
  }`

But I dont wanna it running on migration. I just added `[NotMapped]` decoration on my `Domain` Class.

And it's still not working.

How can I use Views just for consulting in **EF6** ??

Answer (score 0):

Intead using a View in SQL Server, I Created a new Domain Model `Foo.cs`, to my relationship i used `ICollection<bar>` and `ICollection<barz>` and on Mapping i declared both relationship as foregin key.

I just created a outer class like a View Model.